# Wix setup: read several ini files during setup

Tags: installer, wix

For a setup (to update an existing product) I create in wix, I need to read the install directory and process all the *INI-files* that start with settings

Those are settings files who have the same layout, and allow the application to connect to different environments/sql servers. Every ini files configures an environment.

From those files, I need the connectionstring within the ini and run an update SQL-script in every environment (so for each ini file found).

How can that be achieved?

I looked at wix, but did not found a solution.

Now I'm looking to use wix# (wix-sharp), but I don't know if it will be possible.

Thank you in advance for any ideas and thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Using WixSharp just create an ElevatedCustomAction in which you can then do whatever you want - parsing ini files and running sql commands would then be very easy to do...

Comment: It seems to me that the question is asking how to do the ‘‘easy’’ part —  how to read the INI files and run SQL scripts.

Comment: maybe, but I was answering the last question: "Now I'm looking to use wix# (wix-sharp), but I don't know if it will be possible." - so I do not think I was that far off...